# Why is my text going outside div?

Tags: html, css

This is my content of the html . Here the text is not going inside. It is just flying outside

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/proj_css.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class = 'header'>
        <div class = 'header-top'>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"  style="font-size:18px; color: #656565 ; padding-right :25px;"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"  style="font-size:18px; color: #656565 ; padding-right :25px;"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus"  style="font-size:18px; color: #656565 ;"></i>
            <span id = 'top'>
            <a> MY ACCOUNT</a> <a> LOG IN </a> <a> REGISTER </a> <a> CONTACT US</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class = 'header-menu'>
             <a class = "userLink" >L</a><a class = "userLink" id = 'pink'>OG</a> <a class = "userLink" >O </a>

             <ul id = 'horizontal-list'>
                <li><a>HOME &nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a>WEFTED BUNDLES &nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a>CLOSURES &nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a>CLIP-INS &nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a>COLORED WELFED BUNDLES &nbsp</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css :

```
.header-top{
padding-left : 178px;
padding-right : 178px;
 height: 41px;

}
hr {
display: block;
height: 1px;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;


}

ul{ 
padding-left : 0px;
width : 300px;
}


i{

padding-top : 12px; 

}

#horizontal-list a{
font-family : Lato;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 23px;  
}

.header-top a{
font-family : Lato;
font-size : 14px;
color: #656565 ;
padding-left : 24px;
text-align: left;
}
a#pink{
color : #E25889;
}
ul#horizontal-list {
min-width: 696px;
list-style: none;



}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
    
}


a.userLink {

height: 136px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 48px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
line-height: 26px;
}
span#top{

padding-left : 470px;
}
.header-menu span{
vertical-align : middle;
}
.header-menu{
padding-left : 178px;
padding-right : 178px;
 height: 136px;
}
```

I tried a lot to do about it but i was unable to do it. I just want the text in front of the text LOGO as in the image ..
[Look at the image . The text is going out of the div with class header-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAZ0V.jpg)

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the issue. Are you using more CSS that's not listed here?

Comment: by default ul is block element so it's logic what you get unless you share more code

Comment: Did you even try to run the code you posted here? It doesn't correspond at all to the image you posted as a result....

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you want the 'logo' part to be on the left side of the header.

You need to do a 'float:left' to that image. I think the easiest way to do that may be to add some css to '.userLink'

so it should look something like this in your .css file:

```
.userLink {
  float:left;
}
```

See if that works.